# Passing NetworkCredential to HttpWebRequest in C# from ASP.Net Page

Tags: asp.net, http, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to use HTTPWebRequest to access a web service, and am having problems passing credentials in, see code below. I can see the credentials object, nc, being built in the debugger, and also in the assignment to request.Credentials, but when I get to the last line of code it faults with a not authorized error message.  I've had our server folks watch the request on the server, and there are no credentials being passed.  Am I doing something wrong with the Credentials object, or is there something I need to do that I'm not doing here?

```
Uri requestUri = null;
Uri.TryCreate("https://mywebserver/webpage"), 
    UriKind.Absolute, out requestUri);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create
    (requestUri);

NetworkCredential nc =
    new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

request.Credentials = nc;

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to see for yourself what you're passing?  I dislike relying on server folks to evaluate things like this :)

Comment: JustLoren - I didn't know about Fiddler until you posted this comment, I downloaded it and under the Auth tab it says No Proxy-Authorization Header is present. No Authorization Header is present, so I'm still thinking there is something wrong with my code.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not generating a proxy class to call an internal web service?

Comment: Yes, the service I'm calling is a REST service so there is no wsdl file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Premier Support finally helped me solve this problem by using the CredentialCache class to add the Credentials and the "Basic" authorization:

```
NetworkCredential nc =
    new NetworkCredential(GetSetting("username"), GetSetting("password"));
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();

cache.Add(requestUri, "Basic", nc);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);
```

Comment: not using ss l , will the password will be transferred in clear text ?

Answer (score 15):

The NetworkCredentials are either extremely non-intuitive, or flaky, or both.  Regardless, you can solve the issue by bypassing NetworkCredentials altogether and use this method (which I found, courtesy of mark.michaelis.net)

```
/* http://mark.michaelis.net/Blog/CallingWebServicesUsingBasicAuthentication.aspx */
byte[] credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(username + ":" +password);
req.Headers["Authorization"] ="Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);
```

So what you're doing is manually creating a header for your HttpWebRequest and inserting the content as it would appear in a Basic Authentication header. Works like a charm.

Comment: Excellent, this one worked, the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Very nice one! The important thing is that you can pass it directly to the request, leaving the HttpClient static and clean.

Answer (score 2):

It helped me (for Unity3d mono, not ASP.Net):

```
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

Do not need manual set Authorization header or use CredentialCache.

Answer (score 0):

A little off-topic but directly related as I'm working in .NET 7 with HttpClient. This snippet shows how to get your Windows credentials to be used for authentication with a REST API.

```
// MS says just just instantiate this once and use
//  that instance until you're done. So, module var
private static HttpClient _HttpCli;

HttpClientHandler hand;
hand = new HttpClientHandler();
hand.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
hand.PreAuthenticate = true;
_HttpCli = new HttpClient(hand);
```