# C# Set Credential Only Once For Multiple Requests

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest, credentials, networkcredentials

I'm writing a program in visual studio 2010 using C# .Net.

The program will access multiple parts of the website (different urls), and I'm using `HttpWebRequest` and `NetworkCredential` to set username and password.

Right now, every time I send in a request, I have to set the credential. Is there a way to set the credential only once through out the whole process?

```
public void setCredential(string url)
{    
    //set username and password    
    //and get response    
}

public void Main()    
{ 
    string[] URLs= { url1, url2, url3 };    
    foreach (string url in URLs)    
    {    
        setCredential(url);    
    }
}
```

Like I mentioned, by doing it this way, every time I go to a new url I will have to set the credential, which makes it slow sometimes.

I tried to set the credential outside the foreach loop but then I was not able to get response for url2 and url3.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it?

-- Edit 10:26am --

Sorry if I'm not clear.

What I meant is that every time I try to access a url, I had to re-send the username and password over to the server.

So for the sample code, I will have to send the username and password 3 times for 3 different url.

I would like to know if I can send the username and password only once and access all 3 different urls.

ps. All 3 urls are accessible with the same username and password.

Comment: class variables could help.

Comment: @David can you explain more in using class variable? From my understanding I will still have to send the username and pw to the server every time I call a different url.

Comment: can you use cookies or sessions to save credentials?

Comment: no, the program is a executable, it's standalone so I don't think I can save the credential in cookies. Accessing the url is like downloading file from that url, so the idea is the there will be many urls, the user can run the exe and leave it running, and the program terminates when all the files are downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Passing NetworkCredential to HttpWebRequest in C# from ASP.Net Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683398/passing-networkcredential-to-httpwebrequest-in-c-sharp-from-asp-net-page)

This link is showing NetworkCache, this may be a solution for you.

Comment: It looks like CredentialCache class is multiple credentials for one request, but I'm looking for one credential for multiple requests(urls). Or does it work that way also??