# HtmlAgilityPack LoadHtml Unauthorized 401

Tags: asp.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

We are trying to make a parsing over an intranet site. The html response is Ok.

The problem is to load the string html in the class HtmlDocument.

We are getting a 401 Unauthorized status. What I don't understand is why this status if there is no http request when loading from string.

Our code is as follows:

..................

```
           WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
            Stream answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader _answer = new StreamReader(answer);
            string responseText = _answer.ReadToEnd();

 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument resultat = new 
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
             resultat.LoadHtml(responseText);
```

---

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> there is no http request

There is a `WebReq` variable in your code and it will connect to the server to get the response. In term of 401 error, if it's intranet site then probably you can use one of those solution from this link [Passing NetworkCredential to HttpWebRequest in C# from ASP.Net Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683398/passing-networkcredential-to-httpwebrequest-in-c-sharp-from-asp-net-page)

Comment: There is no problem with the WebReq and WebResp. The response comes with no problem. The 401 error appears when the HtmlDocument  LoadHtml line is executed.

Comment: What was the value of your web response at that time?

Comment: The response is the html from the page that I need to scrape. For now, I'm parsing with String.IndexOf, not so good as parsing with HAP.